# Should I use PHP or CSS in order to "hide" html?

Tags: php, html, css, templates, display

I would like to create different css-templates for a html page in order to  offer several designs for that page.
Because not every html element should be shown in every single design I need to hide/deactivate some elements in some templates.

What is best practise to hide these elements without slowing down the page:
Should I use display:none in my css in order to make it disappear or should I use a php-constant, that is swictching these elements on or off?

Thank you!

Comment: You should use php switch to on/off the content it will make sure that less data is transferred over network and also if you use `display:none;` than also it can viewed in page source. If you are not using any Server side language then `display:none;` would do

Comment: applying such styles from css is much easier than applying it from php. So stick with css.

Comment: you should use switch statement in php to display particular result based upon the criteria you've set either if you use css instead it will visible in inspect element and view page source

Comment: I've just decided, that it is imprtant to me ro delete it out of the DOM tree...

Answer (score 1):

You are working on **css-templates for a html page** then use html and css only. Because php is a server side scripting language and so use it only when it is required. So use css:

```
display:none;
```

Comment: Thank you. But with css, it stays in the DOM, right? I am afraid, that this will slow down the page-speed...

Comment: In case of Php, the request goes to server and then process there and response comes back this is a long and resource taking process in comparison to that one

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP to 'hide' the element, it is no longer in the DOM tree. You will not be able to manipulate it with js, like to show it again. 
If just change the CSS style, it is just not visible, but the element is still in the document.
So if you don't want to reload the entire page, you shall use CSS and js. If you want reload page everytime you change the DOM, you can use PHP.